# Entity Framework generate extra foreign keys in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have the following classes, it's all good. But in the table generated in database I found in the `AB` table:

```
Id, AId, BId
```

How is it supposed to be and two additional column that shouldn't be there AId1 & AId2 that they are also foreign keys.

Class A

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
```

Class B

```
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
```

Class AB

```
public class AB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public int BId { get; set; }
}
```

ABMapping

```
public class ABMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AB>
{
        public ABMap()
        {
            this.HasKey(a => a.Id);

            this.HasRequired(e => e.A)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.AId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            this.HasRequired(c => c.B)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.BId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            this.Property(e => e.AId)
                    .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_AB", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
            this.Property(e => e.BId)
                    .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_AB", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
        }
    }
```

Context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        //...
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ABMap());
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the collection property when you call `WithMany`. Because you don't tell EF the two `ABs` collections are part of the relationships you define then two additional One to Many relationships are created. Change your fluent API mapping to the following.

```
public class ABMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AB>
{
    public ABMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(a => a.Id);

        this.HasRequired(e => e.A)
            .WithMany(a => a.ABs)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.AId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.Property(a => a.AId);

        this.HasRequired(c => c.B)
            .WithMany(b => b.ABs)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.Property(a => a.BId);

        this.Property(e => e.AId)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_AB", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
        this.Property(e => e.BId)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_AB", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
    }
}
```